# SQL select to get specific data depending on column length

Tags: sql

I have column `COACODE` storing data like this

```
ID      COACODE
----------------
1       102000

2       1310104
```

We can see here first record has 6 digits and second record has 7 digits 
now i want split the `COACODE` to 3 parts

if `COACODE`= 6 digits length
execute this select ;

```
select SUBSTR(COACODE, 1, 3) as ENTITY_CODE,SUBSTR(COACODE, 4, 2)as BRANCH_CODE ,SUBSTR(COACODE, 6, 1)as  DG_CODE,C.ARABDESC
FROM COACODES c
where CODETYPE=14;
```

if `COACODE`= 7 digits length
execute this select ;

```
select SUBSTR(COACODE, 1, 3) as ENTITY_CODE,SUBSTR(COACODE, 4, 2)as BRANCH_CODE ,SUBSTR(COACODE, 6, 2)as  DG_CODE,C.ARABDESC
FROM COACODES c
where CODETYPE=14;
```

So, how i can solve this in SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: I just check in Oracle. Just using `SUBSTR(COACODE, 6, 2)` will also give you desired result. As for first string, there is only `6th` character, it will return `0`. For second one, it will return `04`, which is what you want.

So depending on your DB, you can try this.

But to answer your question, use `case`.

```
select SUBSTR(COACODE, 1, 3) as ENTITY_CODE,
SUBSTR(COACODE, 4, 2)as BRANCH_CODE ,

case when length(COACODE) = 6 
then SUBSTR(COACODE, 6, 1) 
else 
SUBSTR(COACODE, 6, 2)
end as  DG_CODE

FROM COACODES c
where CODETYPE=14;
```

You can also use just `substr` and use `case` inside it like

```
substr(COACODE,6,case when length(COACODE)=6 then 1 else 2 end)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select SUBSTR(COACODE, 1, 3) as ENTITY_CODE,SUBSTR(COACODE, 4, 2)as BRANCH_CODE ,
SUBSTR(COACODE, 6, Len(COACODE)-6 )as  DG_CODE,C.ARABDESC 
FROM COACODES c
where CODETYPE=14;
```

I am using `SUBSTR(COACODE, 6, Len(COACODE)-6 )` so even in the future if the length of `COACODE` increases it wont be a problem